# Full-text-search on mongoDB using Compass

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

I am using [MongoDB Compass](https://www.mongodb.com/products/compass). I'm creating my queries in Compass query language (programming-language-agnostic, so I can port it over to other languages later via Compasss). My problem? I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong in this query. There are no docs explaining MongoDB Compass syntax for `$search`.

[image]

My indexed text field is called `markdown_1`, my query is "my" (or whatever the user enters), and the object that is being searched looks like this:

[image]

How do I get this query to return anything? As of now, it finds nothing.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think there is a _"Compass Query Language"_.  The Compass aggregation just has the usual stages available to any MongoDB client.  As far as I know, the [`"$search"` stage](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/atlas-search/query-syntax/#mongodb-pipeline-pipe.-search) is limited to MongoDB Atlas.

Comment: So I kind of figured that, but I have my Compass account connected to an Atlas database, and I still have the option to use `$search` in the aggregation pipeline dropdown menu, suggesting it's useable, it just has no instructions, so I can't figure out how.

Comment: There is lots of documentation for Atlas Search.  Perhaps a good starting point is [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/atlas-search/tutorial/).